# Java Eclipse plugin Development - Save all project's files programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for Eclipse.
I'd like it to suggest the user to save unsaved resources before running.
This is in a similar behavior to how eclipse suggest you to save unsaved files before debugging.

In essence, I would like to open the following dialog:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Maybe the sources of that plugin (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142547/eclipse-autosave-plugin/1142568#1142568) might help? Combined with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157016/how-do-i-stop-an-eclipse-editor-from-closing-in-an-rcp/2157673#2157673

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hit alt-shift-F1 on that dialog, you will see which plugin it is in, and then you could either trigger that action, or call that code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using **dplass's** tip I reached this solution, which works perfectly. I'm putting it here for other people who might encounter this problem:

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class SaveOpenFilesHandler extends org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.SaveScopeResourcesHandler
{   
       public void showSaveDialog(IProject project)
       {
           super.showSaveDialog(new IProject[] {project}, true, true);
           super.doSave();
       }
}
```