# Java Eclipse plugin Development - Save all project's files with opening of dialog with list of changed files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This question is already posted in link [Java Eclipse plugin Development - Save all project's files programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897233/java-eclipse-plugin-development-save-all-projects-files-programmatically)

I was trying with the below code but it is not working/ So I have the query that what entry I would required to add in plugin.xml so that as I use ctrl+s or ctrl+all+ save icon below should start working. Or its better if I got complete example.

```java
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class SaveOpenFilesHandler extends org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.SaveScopeResourcesHandler
{   
       public void showSaveDialog(IProject project)
       {
           super.showSaveDialog(new IProject[] {project}, true, true);
           super.doSave();
       }
}
```

Comment: It i not at all clear how the original answer intended this code to be used. It is based on code which only works when launching a program and in any case uses **internal** classes which means it is breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `IDE.saveAllEditors` method is the closest official API for this:

```
public boolean saveAllEditors(IResource[] resources, boolean confirm)
```

> Save all dirty editors in the workbench that are open on files that
>   may be affected by this operation. Opens a dialog to prompt the user
>   if confirm is true. Return true if successful. Return false if the
>   user has canceled the command. Must be called from the UI thread.

The simplest call to this is:

```
IDE.saveAllEditors(new IResource[]{ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()}, true);
```

to save everything in the workspace.

`IDE` is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE`

Comment: But i think it will save all files whether active or not or editable or not? So is this the right way to do this?

Comment: It saves files open in editors which are currently 'dirty' (modified and not saved).

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with on early start up now it is working fine for me.