# Is there a way to either remove or disable the "X" close button shown on a Editor part?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to hide "X" close button from editor part in my eclipse rcp application. Is there any way to hide close button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a possible solution see [How do I stop an Eclipse Editor from closing in an RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157016/how-do-i-stop-an-eclipse-editor-from-closing-in-an-rcp).

Hiding the "X" is not possible (without modifying the framework or writing your own presentation).

Comment: I tried the above options but in my case i dont want to make editor dirty, Is there anyway to prevent close button without making editor dirty?